# Ubuntu 16.04 RT3290 keeps disconnecting/connecting

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, ralink

I'm new to this so please be gentle when helping as I am not familiar with protocol (also 75 years old and maybe not a computer expert).

I have a HP Envy system 64 bit.  I've read every post I can find and nothing seems to help.  Can I just remove my RT3290 driver and, I guess, reboot and automatically be running with a generic WIFI driver?  I don't need bluetooth.

If so how do I remove the driver?  Not sure what directory/folder it is in.

Also, if someone does answer my question, I am not sure how to view the answer.  Will I be notified.  This is my first post but I am at wits end.

Maybe someone could email me at dick@kuzara.com and tell me how to view an answer?